# Google Pay Decrypt Direct Token using php

Tags: php, token, google-pay

I'm looking for some help decrypting a Google Pay response using PHP. I'm using the JavaScript API and the Direct method https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/setup.
The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any PHP library that supports decrypting an ECv2 message.

Has anyone done this successfully or written an article on it?

Comment: Wouldn't you just be sending that token on to your payment gateway like braintree, or authorizenet? Its much like how Apple Pay does their tokenized card data (different algorithms though).

Comment: I have to implement direct integration. My payment provider isn't supported. Can you help me to decrypt token?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't... I've not worked with Google Pay without a card gateway that just accepted the token directly (made things MUCH easier). I did do some searches as well and did not find any decent (or any!) php libraries. Only that "Tink" library, which is nowhere near php, and would require writing an interface to use it, and well, ugh. Sorry!

Comment: It looks like Tink is available for Python which is preinstalled on any Linux server. It's not that hard to make PHP call Python or any of the other supported languages. Just use the shell_exec command https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php.

Answer (score 0):

The [Payment data cryptography for merchants page](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography) refers to the [Tink library](https://github.com/google/tink).

Note that there is no PHP support in the Tink library itself, however it looks like it is possible using a [PHP/Java bridge](https://github.com/google-pay/tink-jni-examples/blob/master/docs/PHP-HOWTO.md).